# Why doesn't authentication work in production in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-authorization

So I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core and working on deploying an application to a production server. I'm using the standard authentication / Entity Framework libraries and that works fine. However, when I protect a page using `[Authorize]` attribute, it works on my dev machine but not on production. I don't have anything unusual in my `Startup.cs` class and there is no `IsDevelopment` clause:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Which kind of production server are you using? Is there any error message or log information about the authentication not working? And, can you post the related code in the ConfigureServices method or can you post details steps to reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem and find the issue. Besides, I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271862/), it seems that perhaps the issue is related to the server configuration.

Comment: I'm using a Windows Server 2019, so not Apache like the other thread. I'll post code tomorrow when I'm at my dev box. The authentication works fine. I can't get to my default page until I log in. It's the controller methods are not protected when decorated with the [Authorize] attribute. I can reach protected pages when not logged in.

Comment: If you don't mind to share your ConfigureServices method from startup.cs, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If all methods require authorization try placing the [Authorize] above the controller class:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

This will require the user to be authenticated to run any action within the controller. I am not sure why it wouldn't be working at the action level unless there is something else overriding it at the controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your AppSettings.json and appsettings.development.json is same.